# Trying To Place An Image In A Table Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

`<img>` element is always empty. I've tried creating different loops and using other methods, but nothing seems to fix the error. Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cards = new Array();
    for(i = 0; i > 11; i++) {
        cards[i] = new Image();
        cards[i].src = "imgs/CardBack.jpg";
        document.theImage.src == cards[i].src;
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<table border="1" width="200px" height="400px">
    <tr>
        <td><img name="theImage"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `document.theImage.src == cards[i].src;` is NOT correct (should be `document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].setAttribute('src',cards[i].src)`. Also, why are you creating an image object and, then, setting the src of a DOM image that may have nothing to do with the current image object that you have just created? I might be wrong, but I think you are slightly confused. Can you please explain what you are trying to do? what is the output you're expecting?

Comment: I'm trying to receive the output that the image will be placed inside the table cell. This process will repeat to fill all the cells of the table with the image.

Comment: Isn't it easier to `<img src="imgs/CardBack.jpg">` ? :) If you want to dinamically parse the same image inside every cell you will have to loop inside each cell, therefore you need to : 1) iterate through every <tr>. 2) iterate through every <li>. 3) append an image tag to every <li> element. Also, you may want to do i < 11, not i > 11 :)

Comment: That was more or less the idea. Since each table will then be assigned an ID, I will be able to randomly place a different image the table. The end product is supposed to be a game of Pairs. Thanks for all your suggestions and explanations thus far.

Comment: Do you need to generate a dynamic amount of cells or..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to access src attribute of "theImage", I suggest you `document.getElementsByName('theImage')[0].setAttribute('src', cards[i].src);`.

Edit : Complete solution after bug tracking here : https://jsfiddle.net/oqbkhb64/2/

Cheers

Comment: Much appreciated. Hasn't seemed to fix the error however.

Comment: I think your for loop and your "new Image()" call is buggy, I think that writing document.getElementByName('theImage')[0].setAttribute('src', 'imgs/CardBack.jpg'); has to work if there is an image at 'imgs/CardBack.jpg' ;) try it !

Comment: Seems like there could possibly be an error with the directory?

Comment: I moved and renamed the image but still isn't appearing. Any ideas?

Comment: First, try to access the image on your server directly, not in your HTML. Like http://localhost/imgs/CardBack.jpg, does it work ? (use your own website root, not localhost)

Comment: The image loads when accessing it locally. Just not with HTML

Comment: Ok, do you have any errors in JS ? Do you know that you can also use <img src="my-url-which-works-directly.jpg" /> ? Cheers

Comment: Okay, so it means that your JS is buggy ! You need to debug that. Use a console to see the errors, or create a snippet on jsfiddle.net if you want to show us an error. Cheers

Comment: Nothing is appearing inside the console. Thanks for your help thus far. I created a JSFiddle if you'd like to take a look

Comment: Haha there is 2 errors : 
- You put a wrong sign '<' in your for loop
- I mispelled you the function to call (getElementS and not getElement)

I have fixed this in this jsfiddle update : https://jsfiddle.net/oqbkhb64/2/
I'm going to edit the post with the answer, please mark it as solved :)
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Code has a few errors, try the following

```
var cards = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    cards[i] = new Image();
    cards[i].src = "imgs/CardBack.jpg"
    document.theImage.src = cards[i].src;
}
```

Hope it works

Comment: Hasn't seemed to fix it. Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[getelementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)** method to get all the `<td>` elements, and then in a loop create an image and assign it to each td:

**HTML:**

```
<table border="1" width="200px" height="400px" id="myTable">
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable"); 
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { 
   var img=document.createElement("img");
   img.src="imgs/CardBack.jpg";
   cells[i].appendChild(img);     
}
```

This is a [**DEMO Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tmovfc75/).